# prestashop module x13allegro update error

Tags: php, apache, logging, module, prestashop

i have transfered my prestashop to the new server, basically i'm new to working with logs, so i would appreciate help with understanding what it says me to do.

Presta shop works fine after migration i have a problem with 1 module, x13allegro while trying to update that module, the logs give me this messages:

```
[Thu Sep 28 21:14:32.005609 2017] [:error] [pid 10361] [client 194.28.220.210:61470] PHP Warning:  tempnam(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/srv_obuwie-wenecja_pl:/var/sentora/temp/) in /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/srv_obuwie-wenecja_pl/modules/x13allegro/classes/php5/XAllegroUpdate.php on line 0, referer: http://srv.obuwie-wenecja.pl/admin3525/index.php?controller=AdminXAllegroConfiguration&token=da55688d9eea9e289f7f23c0e76813ec&update_module

[Thu Sep 28 21:14:32.005798 2017] [:error] [pid 10361] [client 194.28.220.210:61470] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/srv_obuwie-wenecja_pl/modules/x13allegro/classes/php5/XAllegroUpdate.php on line 0, referer: http://srv.obuwie-wenecja.pl/admin3525/index.php?controller=AdminXAllegroConfiguration&token=da55688d9eea9e289f7f23c0e76813ec&update_module

[Thu Sep 28 21:14:32.005825 2017] [:error] [pid 10361] [client 194.28.220.210:61470] PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::open(): Empty string as source in /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/srv_obuwie-wenecja_pl/modules/x13allegro/classes/php5/XAllegroUpdate.php on line 0, referer: http://srv.obuwie-wenecja.pl/admin3525/index.php?controller=AdminXAllegroConfiguration&token=da55688d9eea9e289f7f23c0e76813ec&update_module
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see: tempnam(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Check your PHP settings and alter the open_basedir settings (you could set it to 'none').

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Did you clear your cache? If not, please clear it. Also, have a look at [this](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404214/how-do-i-set-the-path-for-open_basedir) article.